# How To use Pysark Window Function on new unprocessed data?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have developed window functions on pyspark DataFrame to calculate Total Transaction Amount made by customer on monthly basis per transaction.

For Eg:

Input Table has data:

[image: Input Table]

And the window function process the data and inserts it into table

[image: Processed Table]

Now, if i get new transactions today, I want to develop a code where it loads the last month transaction into spark dataframe and running window function on new rows and saving it into Processed Table. The current window function will process all the rows and then need to manually avoid already inserted records and insert only new records. This will use high resources and high memory, when the window function becomes for a year.

```
#Function to apply window function
def cumulative_total_CR(df, from_column, to_column, window_function):
    intermediate_column = from_column + "_temp"
    df = df.withColumn(from_column,df[from_column].cast("double"))

    df = df.withColumn(intermediate_column,when(col("Flow") == 'C',df[from_column]).otherwise(0))

    df = df.withColumn(to_column, F.sum(intermediate_column).over(window_function))

    return df

def cumulative_total_DR(df, from_column, to_column, window_function):
    intermediate_column = from_column + "_temp"
    df = df.withColumn(from_column,df[from_column].cast("double"))

    df = df.withColumn(intermediate_column,when(col("Flow") == 'D',df[from_column]).otherwise(0))

    df = df.withColumn(to_column, F.sum(intermediate_column).over(window_function))

    return df

#Window Function:

window = (Window.partitionBy("CUSNO").orderBy(F.col(TxnDateTime).cast('long')).rangeBetween(-30,0))

df = load.data.from.hive
#appending TxnDate and TxnTime into new column TxnDateTime with type casting as timestamp and format as 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'
df = cumulative_total_CR(df, "TXNAMT", "Total_Cr_Monthly_Amt", window_function_30_days)
df = cumulative_total_DR(df, "TXNAMT", "Total_Dr_Monthly_Amt", window_function_30_days)                               

df = saving.data.to.disk for new records
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with the code oh how you are performing the same so that we can see some ways to help...

Comment: I have edited the question and added the pseudo code. Kindly look into it.

Comment: Few clarifications, Are you reading from Hive ?
Stating you get a new transaction today you want to pick last month transactions do you just want to go 30 days back and pick records from that date or say example today is 23 Oct you get a transaction you want to pick only the records of Sep Month and process them alone

Comment: Yes. Data is fetched from data lake, which in this case is hive. The processing is done on Last 30 days record. Which is configurable... 30 days for approx a month or 7 days for a week or 365 days for a year.

Comment: In that case it would be easier to just pull the last 30 days records from Hive and proceed with the processing. Do you foresee any other issues or complications ?

Comment: currently the process is the same, but there is no point in running the code for yesterdays transaction as i will be discarding it. Secondly if you increase the days to 365 records, for 1st time insert into the table is fine, but after that there is no point in doing it, as you need processing for today's new record. Spark memory allocation as well as time for the the process to execute will become a issue.

Comment: Bit confused, so you mean to say that you want to just process for the current day record rather than process for a month...Sorry for the trouble, just getting my understanding clear